# Page Submission Issue Using AJAX In PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have  a codeigniter application.This is my code in view page.

```
function click_next(){

var aname = $("#txtuname").val();
var apasswd = $("#txtupass").val();
if(aname == ''){
    $("#error_val").css("display","block")
    $("#error_val").html("user name required");
    });
}else if(apasswd == ''){
    $("#error_val").css("display","block")
    $("#error_val").html("password required");
}else{ 
    var cnt=$("#alogin").serialize();
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/adminLogin/",
        data: cnt,
        success: function(msg){
        if(msg==1){
        window.location="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/adminHome/";
        }
        else{
        $("#error_val").css("display","block")
        $("#error_val").html(msg);
        return false;
                }
            }  
        });
}
```

}

Here `alogin` is the name of the form and `url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/adminLogin/"` is the function path in controller page.

This is the code in Controller page

```
function adminLogin(){
         $this->adminmodel->admin_login();

    }
```

This is the code in Model page

```
function admin_login(){
        $adminname=$this->input->post('txtuname');
        $adminpass=$this->input->post('txtupass');
        $adminp_decr=md5($adminpass);
        $this->db->where('varuname',$adminname);
        $this->db->where('varpassword',$adminp_decr);
        $query = $this->db->get('tbladmin');
        $row=$query->row();
        if($row==TRUE){
            $adminname=$row->varuname;
            $id=$row->intaid;
            $userdata = array(
                        'ausername=' =>$adminname,
                        'aid' => $id,
                        'logged_in' => TRUE
                       );

            $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
            echo 1;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Invalid user name or password";     
        }

    }
```

But when i click on the Login buttton nothing will happen(the click_next() is called and given admin,admin as username ,password).What is the reason?This is working in our server But not working in client's server?

Comment: when iam using firebug the url path in red color.There have Posts txtuname admin
txtupass admin
Source
txtuname=admin&txtupass=admin   .But No Responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're posting to the controller method, I would recommend grabbing the POST variables in that method and passing them via parameters to the model function.  According to MVC, the controller should be working with POST variables and not the model.

Try this:

```
function adminLogin(){
     $adminname=$this->input->post('txtuname');
     $adminpass=$this->input->post('txtupass');

     if (strlen($adminname) > 0 && strlen($adminpass) > 0)
         echo $this->adminmodel->admin_login($adminname, $adminpass);
     else
         echo "you didn't enter anything.... duh.";
    }


function admin_login($adminname="", $adminpass=""){
        $adminp_decr=md5($adminpass);
        $this->db->where('varuname',$adminname);
        $this->db->where('varpassword',$adminp_decr);
        $query = $this->db->get('tbladmin');
        $row=$query->row();
        if($row==TRUE){
            $adminname=$row->varuname;
            $id=$row->intaid;
            $userdata = array(
                        'ausername=' =>$adminname,
                        'aid' => $id,
                        'logged_in' => TRUE
                       );

            $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return "Invalid user name or password";     
        }

    }
```

It's a minor change, but the code adheres more to MVC principles.  Plus, I suspect that your POST variables might not be making it past the call to the model's admin_login() method.

Comment: No nothing will happen.This is working in our sever but not working in client's server

Comment: I noticed you're using $base_url with index.php. You shoul change that to $site_url and take out the index.php. I'm not sure if you're using mod_rewrite to strip out the index.php but $site_url is more portable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't handle the case where "invalid username" is returned by the ajax call and just silently fail.

Your `if (msg == 1)` should at the very least have an `else` clause:

```
if(msg==1){
           window.location="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/adminHome/";
} else {
   alert(msg);
}
```

and the server-side login function should at least check that a username and a password have been passed in, not just blanks.

Comment: ok now its working it is the problem of base_url in config.php page